# Chrome: play audio on two outputs with HTMLAudioElement.setSinkId

Tags: google-chrome, html5-audio, mediastream

I want to play the same audio MediaStream on two different audio output media devices with the following code:

```js
const audio0 = new Audio('/audio.mp3')
audio0.play()

const stream = audio0.captureStream()

const audio1 = new Audio()
audio1
  .setSinkId('552a19eb3a0e0c496c1967d4d503f1fe78f66eb213b3bea48ba5b2f672bb1241')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('audio1 setSinkId was successful', audio1.sinkId)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('audio1 setSinkId failed', err.name, err.message)
  })
audio1.srcObject = stream
```

The setSinkId call is successful and `audio1.sinkId` is set to the right device id `'[ID]'` (internal speakers), however, the result is both audio0 and audio1 play on `'default'` device (paired bluetooth headphones).

I would expect audio0 play on the default device, while audio1 should play on the other, specified by deviceId `'ID'`.

Curiously, if I `setSinkId` audio0 to play on device `'[ID]'` and just let audio1 play on the default, it works, I get to hear the audio on both devices simultaneously.

```js
const audio0 = new Audio('/audio.mp3')
.setSinkId('552a19eb3a0e0c496c1967d4d503f1fe78f66eb213b3bea48ba5b2f672bb1241')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('audio0 setSinkId was successful', audio0.sinkId)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('audio0 setSinkId failed', err.name, err.message)
  })
audio0.play()

const stream = audio0.captureStream()

const audio1 = new Audio()
audio1.srcObject = stream
```

Comment: Did you resolve it?